# typeof foo['bar'] !== 'undefined' vs. 'bar' in foo

Tags: javascript

What's the difference between the return values of these two expressions...

Expression 1: `typeof foo['bar'] !== 'undefined'`

Expression 2: `'bar' in foo`

... assuming that these conditions are met:

1. `foo` is an object,
2. `foo` does not contain any properties that have the value `undefined` set explicitly.

Comment: How about `foo.hasOwnProperty('bar')`?

Comment: @Rocket no, that's not the same thing - the property accessor expression will also examine the prototype chain.

Comment: @Pointy And the `in` operator too, right?

Comment: @Šime Vidas - yes, `[[HasProperty]]` is defined in terms of `[[GetProperty]]`, not `[[GetOwnProperty]]`.

Comment: Also, I don't think it makes any sense to think of a property as having an explicit "undefined" value - if an object has a property, then its value is *something*, at least `null`, but not "undefined".

Comment: @Pointy Yes, I do not care about properties that are set to `undefined`. But I had to put condition 2 in there because otherwise I would have been flooded with answers pointing out that if a property is set to `undefined`, expression 1 returns `false`, and expression 2 `true`.

Answer (score 5):

The first tests the value of `bar` in `foo`.

The second tests for the existence of the `bar` property in `foo`.

```
var foo = {bar:undefined};

typeof foo['bar'] !== 'undefined'; // false

'bar' in foo;  // true
```

---

**EDIT:**

To add some clarification from the comments below, the issue OP is having is that accessing the `domConfig` property of `window.document` throws an Error.

This is an issue not related to the `typeof` operator, but rather to a specific issue with Firefox.

The issue [has been documented here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=226193) as a bug (back in 2003).

*A few notable comments from that report:*

> **Zbigniew Braniecki [:gandalf] 2003-11-19 09:09:31 PST**
>
> then why it can be iterated with for-in ?
>
> **Boris Zbarsky (:bz) 2003-11-19 09:24:05 PST**
>
> Because it *is* defined as a property on the nsIDOM3Document interface.  It's
>   just one that throws if you try to access its getter. ...
>
> **Zbigniew Braniecki [:gandalf] 2003-11-19 09:33:53 PST**
>
> ... So what kind of bug is it?
>
> The goal is to remove not implemented method/property from interface or to
>   implement it?!?
>
> **Boris Zbarsky (:bz) 2003-11-19 09:53:23 PST**
>
> The goal is to eventually implement this.

Comment: @patrick I've updated my question. I am concerned about the return values of these two expressions...

Comment: @Šime Vidas: Do you mean the type of return value, or the result? The type should be boolean for both, but the result may differ as shown.

Comment: @patrick Condition 2 of my question states that `foo` does not contain any properties that have the value `undefined` set explicitly.

Comment: @Šime Vidas: Is there a specific issue you've encountered? Given Condition 2, the result ought to be the same.

Comment: @patrick Well, actually yes. `typeof document['domConfig']` throws an error in Firefox, whereas `'domConfig' in document` doesn't. If both (generally) produce the same boolean result, I'd rather use `in` to avoid unexpected errors.

Comment: @Šime Vidas: That's odd. I don't get any error in FF4. Yes, either will give a boolean result. Or you could test by comparing to `void 0` as a safe way to check for `undefined`.

Comment: @patrick Try here: http://jsfiddle.net/TvBeT/ - Firefox 4 throws "NS_ERROR_NOT_IMPLEMENTED".

Comment: @Šime Vidas: Yes, sure does. Appears to have nothing to do with `typeof`. Merely attempting to access the property throws the error. Seems like `in` would be the way to go.

Comment: @Šime Vidas: [Here's a bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=226193) originating in 2003.

Comment: @patrick Comment from 7 years ago: *"The goal is to eventually implement this."* They sure are taking their time. `:)`

Comment: @Šime Vidas: Indeed they are. :o) I just updated the answer with that and some of the preceding comments.

Answer (score 2):

My reading of the spec suggests that they should be the same.  The "in" operator semantics are defined in terms of making a call to the internal (conceptual) `[[HasProperty]]` method, which itself is defined in terms of `[[GetProperty]]`.  When `[[HasProperty]]` returns "undefined", then the "in" operator results in boolean `false`; otherwise it's `true`.  Based on the definition of what `[[GetProperty]]` is supposed to do, that means that an "undefined" result of a property access would have the same meaning.

Answer (score 1):

```
var foo = {};
foo.bar = undefined;

console.log("bar" in foo); // true
console.log(typeof foo["bar"] !== "undefined"); // false

var Con = function() {};
Con.prototype.bar = undefined;
var foo = new Con;

console.log("bar" in foo); // true
console.log(typeof foo["bar"] !== "undefined"); // false
```

The `in` check is simply the same as using a `for in` loop and returning true if the `key` is in the `for in` loop.

[Edit] Didn't see your "don't explicity set it to `undefined`" condition.

```
var foo = {}
Object.defineProperty(foo, "bar", { 
    "value": 42,
    "enumerable": false

});

console.log("bar" in foo); // true (in chrome & FF4)
console.log(typeof foo["bar"] !== 'undefined'); // true
```

I actaully expected the `in` test to fail if you set it as non-enumerable. Seems like they are the same.

```
var foo = {}
Object.defineProperty(foo, "bar", { 
    "value": 42,
    "writable": false

});

console.log("bar" in foo); // true (in chrome & FF4)
console.log(typeof foo["bar"] !== 'undefined'); // true
```

Both test still work if the property is "readonly"

```
var foz = {}
Object.defineProperty(foz, "bar", { 
    "value": 42
});
var foo = Object.freeze(foz);

console.log("bar" in foo); // true (in chrome & FF4)
console.log(typeof foo["bar"] !== 'undefined'); // true
```

Freezing the object also doesn't break the tests.

Answer (score 1):

Given the conditions you outline, there is no difference.  Both should produce the same boolean result and should behave the same around prototype lookup.

```
Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(null, foo, 'bar')
```

is another common idiom that does the same as those two but does not incude properties available only on the prototype.

Answer (score 1):

Given those two conditions, the expressions should give you identical results, **except if**

- `foo` has an EcmaScript 5 getter defined for the `bar` property. Since the first expression actually reads the property value, that getter will be invoked. The second expression merely checks for the existence of the property so there is no need to incoke any such getter.
- you are targeting Internet Explorer 4.0 - the `in` operator wasn't added until [JavaScript 1.4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Versions) ;)

---

Here's some [sample code](http://jsfiddle.net/jWBA6/) to illustrate the difference in supporting browsers (Chrome, IE9, FF4):

```
var foo = {};
Object.defineProperty(foo, "bar", { 
    "get": function () {document.write("Getter invoked!<br/>"); return foo;}
});

document.write('"bar" in foo -->' + 
               ("bar" in foo));
document.write('<br/>');
document.write('typeof foo["bar"] !== "undefined" -->' +
               (typeof foo["bar"] !== "undefined"));
document.write('<br/>');
```

Comment: Well the spec says that the "in" operator will call `[[HasProperty]]`, and that is defined as making a call to `[[GetProperty]]`. Won't that invoke the getter too?

Comment: @Pointy I must confess I didn't study the spec in that much detail, but observed the difference in Chrome, FF4 and IE9

Comment: Hmm.  Well, it's certainly an interesting question; it's one of those weird aspects of the language that I never feel 100% sure about.  Better to just avoid the situation whenever possible :-)

Comment: @Pointy: No, `[[GetProperty]]` does not execute the getter, it just builds a *Property Descriptor* based on the property attributes, via `[[GetOwnProperty]]`.

Comment: Ah, OK, now I understand what that means.  Thanks @CMS !!

Answer (score 0):

the first one first checks existence of 'bar' key in foo (undefined is returned if it's not found), then checks the type of that key. 
the second on checks only existence.