# Recommended way to spot undefined variable which have been declared

Tags: javascript

For detect undefined variable which have been declared in javascript there at least two different ways.

```
var bar; // declared variable

if (typeof bar !== "undefined") {
     // make something with bar
}

if (bar) {
     // make something with bar
}
```

My Questions:

1) Are the two ways equal in all the aspects?

2) If not what is the best?

Comment: possible duplicate of [typeof foo\['bar'\] !== 'undefined' vs. 'bar' in foo](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5434368/489560)

Comment: I suggest a check based on the expected type of the variable. For instance, if you expect a string, you can do `if ( bar.length > 0 ) {...}` to only execute code if you have a non-empty string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if (bar) {` will return false for many cases other than an undefined variable.

For instance, if bar is 0 then `if(bar)` will evaluate to false.  bar having a value of `false` will also evaluate to false.

Answer (score 2):

No they are not equal. `if(bar)` will also fail *if the variable is false or [falsy](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/)*. Use the first method with `typeof`

Answer (score 1):

I suppose this is programmer preference but I don't like variables that are undefined. If they are undefined I will assign them some value.

If you have a situation where a variable is either a reference to an object, or it doesn't reference yet:

```
var my_ref; // undefined

function ref(that_obj) {
    my_ref = that_obj;
}

console.log(my_ref);    // undefined
ref({"some": "object"});
console.log(my_ref);    // {"some": "object"}
```

My preference is to initialize it to `false`. This only works ofcourse if `false` is never an expected value. Other values to use are `-1` for numbers or `null`.

Another example:

```
function my_func(arg1, arg2, arg3) {
    if (has_no_value(arg3)) {
        arg3 = "default value";
    }
    console.log(arg1, arg2, arg3);
}
my_func("first", "lol");    // first lol default value
```

Also, I recommend making a function that checks for undefined-ness (`has_no_value` in my case) because it's easy to make a mistake in `typeof arg3 === "undefined"`

`if(arg3)` is false if arg3 is **falsy** which includes `undefined null 0 "" false NaN`

if you want to check for `false` do `if (false === arg3)`

> Type coercion is used in JavaScript with the == and != operators. From
>   Wikipedia: “There are two types of type conversion: implicit and
>   explicit. The term for implicit type conversion is coercion. The most
>   common form of explicit type conversion is known as casting.” What
>   this means is that true and false are converted to numbers before they
>   are compared to a number. When comparing to any of these values: 0,
>   null, undefined, '', true and false, ***Douglas Crockford**, in JavaScript:
>   The Good Parts*, recommends the use of the === or !== operators. In
>   JSLint, there is a “Disallow == and !=” option, which requires the use
>   of === and !== in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

The second one is testing for falsy values which don't necessarily indicate its undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this:

```
var bar;
bar = 0; 
alert (typeof bar !== "undefined")  // alerts true
alert(bar == true) // alerts false
```