# Why does the in operator return true for a property that is undefined?

Tags: javascript

### Description

I always wrongly assumed that the `in` operator was checking for an `undefined` value for the property. A quick look at the [ES5 specification](https://es5.github.io/) shows that the `in` operator eventually calls [`[[GetProperty]]`](https://es5.github.io/#x8.12.2), which would return the value of the property.

Why is it that the when `foo.bar` is set to `undefined` the `in` operator returns `true`, while when `foo.bar` is never set it is `false`, even though they both have a value of `undefined`?

### Example

```
var foo = {
    bar: undefined
};

'baz' in foo
// -> false

'bar' in foo
// -> true
```

Related: [typeof foo['bar'] !== 'undefined' vs. 'bar' in foo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434368/typeof-foobar-undefined-vs-bar-in-foo)
The related questions was asking about when `foo.bar` is never set to `undefined`.

Comment: in just check if the prop is defined on the object or it's inherited objects, not what the value is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note: While researching the question I found the answer, since I have already spent the time, I decided to post what I found.**

---

The reason why they return a different value is that [`[[GetProperty]]`](https://es5.github.io/#x8.7.1) calls [`[[GetOwnProperty]]`](https://es5.github.io/#x8.12.1), which does does not return the property value. `[[GetOwnProperty]]` returns a [Property Descriptor](https://es5.github.io/#x8.10) which describes things like if the property is enumerable, writable and it's value.

When you set a property to `undefined` as with `bar` in the question, a Property Descriptor is created* with a `[[Value]]` of `undefined`. When `[[GetOwnProperty]]` is called for `bar` the Property Descriptor is returned, while with `baz`, `undefined` is returned. This means that `[[GetProperty]]` return a defined value for `bar`, which then makes [`[[HasProperty]]`](https://es5.github.io/#x8.12.6) return `true`, instead of `false`. Which in turn makes the `in` operator return `true` as well.

* *this is a lie, but for simplicity sake.*

### Specification Trace

From [Annotated ECMAScript 5.1](https://es5.github.io/).

**Note:** Numbers below link to Spec reference where possible

For: `'bar' in foo`

- [1.](https://es5.github.io/#x11.8.7) Evaluating `'bar'` gives a string `'bar'`
- [2.](https://es5.github.io/#x8.7.1) `GetValue` of `'bar'` will return the value `'bar'`
- [3.](https://es5.github.io/#x11.8.7) Evaluating `foo` gives a reference `foo`
- [4.](https://es5.github.io/#x8.7.1) `GetValue` of `foo` will return the value of `'foo'`, our object
- [5.](https://es5.github.io/#Type) `Type` of value of `foo` is an object, no exception thrown
- 6. [`toString`](https://es5.github.io/#x9.8) of value of `'bar'` returns the string `'bar`, call [`[[HasProperty]]`](https://es5.github.io/#x8.12.6)

     - [1.](https://es5.github.io/#x8.12.2) `[[GetProperty]]` returns [Property Descriptor](https://es5.github.io/#x8.10) (not `undefined`)
     - [1.](https://es5.github.io/#x8.12.1) `[[GetOwnProperty]]` return Property Descriptor (not `undefined`)
     - 1. `foo` does have own property called `bar`, do not return `undefined`
     - 2. Create a Property Descriptor with no fields
     - 3. Create X from `foo.bar`
     - 4. X is a data property, so set [[Value]] to `undefined` and set `[[Writable]]`
     - 5. Else branch skipped
     - 6. Set [[Enumerable]]
     - 7. Set [[Configurable]]
     - 8. Return Property Descriptor
     - 2. Property Descriptor is not undefined, return the Property Descriptor.
     - 2. Property Descriptor is not `undefined`, so don't return false
     - 3. else, return true